# Why is $\prod_{k=1}^nS(D-\lambda_kI)S^{-1}=S\prod_{k=1}^n(D-\lambda_kI)S^{-1}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, products

I was looking at an answer about matrixes and I found this statement:

$$
\pi_A(A)=\prod_{k=1}^n(A-\lambda_kI)=\prod_{k=1}^nS(D-\lambda_kI)S^{-1}=S\prod_{k=1}^n(D-\lambda_kI)S^{-1}=S\cdot 0\cdot S^{-1}=0
$$

The equations' context was within matrixes and eigenvectors.
But, besides the question context, I don't understand how he was able to go from step 2 to step 3. Meaning, why is this true:

$\prod_{k=1}^nS(D-\lambda_kI)S^{-1}=S\prod_{k=1}^n(D-\lambda_kI)S^{-1}$

Doesn't this break a rule? And if not, which rule supports this operation?

Comment: Try writing it out with, say, $s=3$.

Comment: That's the thing, when I think about it until the S is inside the Phy, it gets multiplied n times, so at the end, the power of S should be n. When S is outside, the power of S at the end will stay 1. Doesn't this make it incorrect?

Comment: $(ABA^{-1})(ACA^{-1})=ABCA^{-1}$ since the internal $A^{-1}A$ cancels.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. What you're saying is that technically the power should indeed be n when $S$ and $S^{-1}$ go out of the Phy. But, because they are one the inverse of the other, all of this cancels out and just $S$ and $S^{-1}$ stay? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Indeed.  So you should have:  $~~\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n\left( S\cdot(A-\lambda_k I)\cdot S^{-1}\right)= S\cdot\left(\prod_{k=1}^n (A-\lambda_k I)\right)\cdot S^{-1}$

Comment: No, saraspagno, the power shouldn't be $n$, not even if there were no cancellation. If you had $(AB_1C)(AB_2C)\cdots(AB_nC)$ you would just get $AB_1CAB_2C\cdots AB_nC$ and there wouldn't be any $A^n$ nor any $C^n$. But if $C$ is $A^{-1}$ then you get cancellations and all that's left is $AB_1B_2\cdots B_nA^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the power would not be $n$ anyway because the $S$'s are not consecutive. What I mean is that the $S$ it's supposed to appear in the final result $n$ times, and if you simply take it out of the Phy, it will appear only once. In this case, the $S$ and $S^{-1}$ cancels out anyway, so it's correct. More generally, in Phy product notation, you wouldn't be allowed to simply pull a const out of the Phy (such as you are with sum notation). That was my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the substitution $B_k = D-\lambda_kI$.
Then,
$$ 
\prod_{k=1}^n (S B_k S^{-1}) 
= (S B_1 S^{-1})(S B_2 S^{-1})\cdots (S B_n S^{-1})  $$
$$= S B_1 (S^{-1} S) B_2 (S^{-1} S) B_3 \cdots (S^{-1} S) B_n S^{-1} $$
$$= S B_1 B_2 \cdots B_n S^{-1} $$
$$= S \left(\prod_{k=1}^n B_k\right) S^{-1}$$
$$= S \left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(D-\lambda_k I \right)\right) S^{-1}.$$